# Ajax receive a collection of objects from Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I currently am attempting to create my own instant messenger for my site (NOT using a plugin - am attempting to hand make this for learning purposes) and I am looking to try to send an ajax request to the server for a list of all messages between two users.  **My question is this: can ajax 'read' a collection of Message objects sent from Laravel (doubt it) or does it need to be formatted in a certain way/manner?**  I initially thought to use lists to get the sender_id along with the message (the order is by date by default), however, I don't think that javascript can read PHP's (not)-arrays.  The only viable solution I have came up with thus far is to send either 1 array with sender_id followed by the message for the entire conversation OR 2 arrays- one with all sender_id's in order and a second with all messages in order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) for communicating between PHP and JavaScript (look up PHP json_encode and json_decode functions), it'll allow you to pass complex arrays almost natively between the languages.

EDIT: a few examples to give some indication how it works, I'm using jQuery for my examples here

**Requesting information from a PHP script via AJAX**:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        for (i in data.messages) {
            output(data.messages[i]);
        }
    }
});
var output = function(message) {
    console.log(message.id);
    console.log(message.sender.id);
};
```

The PHP script can output:

```
$messages = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'message' => 'Awesome',
        'sender' => array(
            'id' => 1, 'name' => 'John',
        ),
    ),
 );
 echo json_encode(array('messages' => $messages));
```

**Sending information using JSON via AJAX**:

```
// Example data object, you can have this infinitely nested
var data = [
    {id: 1, "message": "test" }
];
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
});
var output = function(message) {
    console.log(message.id);
    console.log(message.sender.id);
};
```

The PHP script can then read this using:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
// This becomes a simple 2D PHP array which is an exact representation as your JS object. The above example data can be output as:
foreach ($data as $message) {
    echo $message['id'] . ' - ' .$message['message'];
}
```

Comment: Well, looks like that will work for sending it to the page.  Now, how would I grab each of the elements?

Comment: What do you mean by grab each of the elements? As in sending from the page to php? Encode it using JSON in JavaScript and send it to PHP. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Sorry, I meant as in read the json element once it has been sent to the page.  I have never dealt with a json element so I don't know of it structure nor how to loop over it(or call each part like $message->sender_id in Laravel).

Comment: I added a couple code samples, do they make things a bit more clear?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks a lot mate.